# Is using many npm modules slowing down web application?

Tags: npm, mean-stack

I am building web app based on MEAN stack and like many npm packages.
So I install many on my projects and enjoy using them. However I wonder that is using many npm module(or packages?) slowing down when users visit my website?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Npm prior to version 3 uses nested dependencies, which is why with version 3 they'll be moving to flat structures like Bower. I think loads of nested dependencies could hamper performance a bit.

Comment: I think mine is v3.7.3 and it seems like it is fine, doesn't it? :D